# How To Load Plist Data On HighChart Using Objective C?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, json, highcharts

I am Integrating `HighChart` Into my iPhone application. I am using below `Javascript` file for appearing high `chart`. Here below URL high chart providing data but I want to remove this `URL` and want to read my `Xcode` `plist` data and shown on chart based on that data.

```
https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?
```

Below My Code

```
$(function () {
$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function (data) {

            // Create the chart
            $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

                   rangeSelector : {
                     selected : 1
                   },

                   title : {
                         text : ''
                   },
                  navigator : {
                         enabled : false

                    },
                   plotOptions: {
                        line: {animation: false}
                   },

                   series : [{
                             name : 'AAPL Stock Price',
                             data : data,
                             tooltip: {
                             valueDecimals: 2
                     }
                 }]
    });
       });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

To load a plist element, you can use the `NSDictionary` selectors `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:` or `dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:`

More information: [NSDictionary reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class)

Answer (score 0):

@SteaveJobs Solution you are looking is not possible as https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=? suggests there is a file by name "aapl-c.json" which server will extract json data from and plot graph using `StockChart`as component.

Which i feel you should look for is some thing similar to [Core Plot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot) and its [documentation](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/index.html)